# Custom graph not returning the correct Vertex

Tags: java, graph

I've written a custom class `Graph` for my programming problem. However, the `getVertex` method seems not to work. It should return the `Vertex` which is saving the `Verschiebung` object which is given by parameter. I'm returning null when I'm trying to print a correct Vertex adress in the console. I really can't find the problem in this. The 2D array `feld` is filled with objects of `Planquadrat`. That class works fine, so I didn't include code snippets from there.

`i` and `j` are integers. The declaration isn't shown here.

```
private Planquadrat[][] feld;
private Graph verschiebungen;
public void erstelleGraph() {
    verschiebungen = new Graph();
    Vertex neuerVertex1;
    neuerVertex1 = new Vertex(new Verschiebung(-1, feld[i][j], feld[i+1][j]));
    verschiebungen.addVertex(neuerVertex1);
    System.out.println(verschiebungen.getVertex(
                       neuerVertex1.getVerschiebung()));
}
```

Here is the class Graph:

```
public class Graph{
    private List<Vertex> vertices;
    private List<Edge> edges;

    public Graph(){
        vertices = new List<Vertex>();
        edges = new List<Edge>();
    }

    public Vertex getVertex(Verschiebung pVerschiebung){
        Vertex result = null;
        vertices.toFirst();
        while (vertices.hasAccess() && result == null){
            if (vertices.getContent().getVerschiebung().getVon().equals(pVerschiebung.getVon()) && vertices.getContent().getVerschiebung().getNach().equals(pVerschiebung.getNach())){
                result = vertices.getContent();
            }
            vertices.next();
        }

        return result;
   }

   public void addVertex(Vertex pVertex){
      vertices.append(pVertex);      
   }
}
```

Here is the class Vertex:

```
public class Vertex{
    private Verschiebung verschiebung;
    private boolean mark;

    public Vertex(Verschiebung pVerschiebung){
        verschiebung = pVerschiebung;
        mark = false;
    }

    public Verschiebung getVerschiebung(){
        return verschiebung;
    }
```

Here is the class Verschiebung:

```
public class Verschiebung {

    private int menge;
    private Planquadrat von, nach;

    public Verschiebung (int pMenge, Planquadrat pVon, Planquadrat pNach) {
        menge = pMenge;
        von = pVon;
        nach = pNach;
    }

    public Planquadrat getVon() {
        return von;
    }

    public Planquadrat getNach() {
        return nach;
    }
}
```

On the `List` class: It is a custom class as well and I can guarantee that it works fine since I have used it a lot. The method `append` adds a new object to the end of the list. `toFirst` sets the first object of the list as the current object, `next` sets the current object one element further. `hasAccess` returns if there is still a current object.

Here is the implementation of `equals()` and `hashChode()` of `Planquadrat`:

```
private int x, y;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {

    if (o == this) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Planquadrat)) {
        return false;
    }

    Planquadrat p = (Planquadrat) o;

    return p.x == x &&
           p.y == y;

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 31 * hash + this.x;
    hash = 31 * hash + this.y;
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: Could you please give details about the `List` class you use in class `Graph`? It is obviously _not_ `java.util.List` interface, since you instance it, it has the methods `toFirst()`, `hasAccess()`, `getContent()`, `next()` and `append(Vertex)` (or similar). This class seems to be important, as it is used in the method in question.

Comment: There is also a problem in your first piece of code, the indices `i` and `j` are neither declared nor assigned - should this part be in a loop?

Comment: I added a few notes on the `List` class.

Comment: And yes, you're right. I should mention that `i` and `j` are integers of a loop. This is just a code snippet and I removed the loops.

Comment: Could be a problem with the `equals()` implementation of `Planquadrat` class. And you should get rid of your own `List` class - so far it seems to be a combination of implementations of the `java.util.List` interface with the `java.util.Iterator` interface - could it be that you invented the wheel again? ;-)
Oh to be clear: could you please add the implementations of `equals` and `hashCode` of your `Planquadrat` class - if you have overwritten them?

Comment: Heh, you're right about the `List`. :> But since I already got that class, I wanted to use it anyway.
The `Planquadrat` class doesn't have a `equals()` method. Isn't it the `equals()` method from the `Object` class which is called here? I didn't override any method.

Comment: That's right, but `Object.equals()` is nothing better than `==` - it does not take care about your field values. Best if you let your IDE generate that two methods (equals and hashCode) for you. Always override both of them together! And for your own `List`: if you had used the default implementations, some time on understanding your problem could have been saved (at least for me) and you would not have to stress that you 'can guarantee that it works fine since I have used it a lot' - useless anyway, since using a lot does not guarantee anything... ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167989/discussion-between-cyberbrain-and-firefan).